# Best ways to get only "active" in arrays - get group members

Tags: ether, arrays

let's say I have an group contract where users can join and leave groups. When a user joins a group, his address will be added to members[groupId]. When he lefts, the members[groupId] will be set to 0x0. Let's say members[0] is 2,000 values long. The problem is, that not all of these 2,000 members are active/in the group as some addresses in that array are 0x0 addresses.

Let's say I have now a website where I want to get all active members of group 0.
What are now the best ways to get the active users? A 2,000 times loop in javascript? Or are there maybe more efficient ways to solve it?

Comment: It sounds like you want a _set_. This blog post might help: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/06/03/storage-patterns-set/.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a mapping like `mapping (bool => Member[]) isActiveMembers` with help of which you will be to reduce time complexity of `getActiveMembers` function from O(N) to O(1).

All the active members will have the key `true` and when active members leave the group you can remove the respective member from the mapping `isActiveMembers` with key `true` and insert the same member in the mapping `isActiveMembers` with key `false`.

Let me know if any further clarification is required.